# function in onCreate

Tags: java

i want to know how the function work in onCreate or onCreateView

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);

        functionOne();
        functionTwo();
}
```

I want to know that functionOne and functionTwo work parallel or step by step.Thanks

Comment: You can get the answer by yourself by running the values with logcat or using debug  mode

Comment: What prompts you to ask this question? Why would you expect the program to run any other way than line by line?

Comment: you might be new in android , but you should know programmatically concepts. You might not have idea about android, but you must know other languages like java,C,C++ etc. If you know other languages then concepts and flow will be same, it doesnt matter what language you are using. It will be in flow only.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you don't quite understand how methods in Java work. `functionOne` and `functionTwo` are not "functions", they are *methods*. Java methods is *generally* executed one after another. That means when `functionOne` finishes (returns), `functionTwo` starts being executed. I said generally because you can create a new thread to execute `functionTwo`. That way `functionTwo` is executed asynchronously.